# iOS Swift live streaming: Warning: PART-HOLD-BACK SHOULD be at least three times the Part Target Duration

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming, low-latency

We use `AVPlayer` in order to play live stream in our `iOS` app. We've recently added low-latency feature.

Only when low-latency is enabled: Sometimes player stalls / is frozen.

The following waring is logged:

```
Warning: PART-HOLD-BACK SHOULD be at least three times the Part Target Duration
```

What can we do in order to fix the issue?

PS: We use Mux in Server-side.

Comment: how did u enable LL

Comment: may be u can ask in apple developer forum also ..same question

Comment: We use Mux on server-side and they have the functionality that allows low latency streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link will give more clear information for the error/warning observed.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis

**"The client SHALL choose which Media Segment to play first from the
Media Playlist when playback starts.  If the EXT-X-ENDLIST tag is not
present and the client intends to play the media normally, the client
SHOULD NOT choose a segment closer to the end of the Playlist than
described by the HOLD-BACK and PART-HOLD-BACK attributes.  Doing so
can trigger playback stalls."**
As mentioned here if EXT-X-ENDLIST tag exist for LL, AVPlayer will stall or freeze.

Comment: But AVPlayer does it automatically right? I mean choosing media segments, for example. 
I understand what the problem is, however I don't understand how to fix it. Should I fix it server-side by updating  HOLD-BACK / PART-HOLD-BACK attributes or front-end?

Comment: @Levan Karanadze - yes you need to fix on server-side, it should hv correct manifest and tags

Comment: Got it, thanks! What bout setting AVPlayerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration manually? Will it help?
We don't set it for now and it's managed automatically (default 0).

Comment: no need to set  AVPlayerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration